# Translate detail layout section

Tags: translation, detail-page, detail

I have a custom object ACcount Plan. Is there a way to translate in the ACCount Plan Detail page Account plan Detail section?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be changed. If you really object to it, you could replace the detail page with a Custom Visualforce page. However, it would then be harder for anyone to change the layout in the future.